# Array values not being processed

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-data-structures

I tried to implement a hash, and its key "Foo Bar" has an array as its value.
While I tried to assign hash with this specific key to an array,the resultant array is not working as expected:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

 my %grades;
 $grades{'Foo Bar'}[0] = 23;
 $grades{'Foo Bar'}[1] = 42;
 $grades{'Foo Bar'}[2] = 73;
 my @array = $grades{'Foo Bar'};

 foreach my $myval ( @array )
 {
         print $myval;
 }
```

Where exactly has it gone wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The hash value is a *reference to* an array, a scalar value. Copying it into an array as you have done results in an array with one element equal to the array reference

You need to *dereference* the value to access the referenced array. You can dereference it directly like this

```perl
for my $val ( @{ $grades{'Foo Bar'} } ) {
    print $val, "\n";
}
```

Or you can copy it into a scalar variable first, as I show in my code below

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %grades;

$grades{'Foo Bar'}[0] = 23;
$grades{'Foo Bar'}[1] = 42;
$grades{'Foo Bar'}[2] = 73;

my $array = $grades{'Foo Bar'};

for my $val ( @$array ) {
    print $val, "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
23
42
73
```